# What does 'indexes' do in sql query

Tags: sql, constraints, check-constraints

I come to know that this is used to speed up data retrieval..I like to know more about it .Thanks .

Comment: For simple, It is `Keys` that refer to each of your records. It is sorting and used to help searching your records faster. For more, use your google skill.

Comment: there are  many questions in SO and DBA.SE which covers the topic,start with them and if you have any question in those ask

Comment: http://use-the-index-luke.com/

Answer (score 1):

Indexing is a way of sorting a number of records on multiple fields. Creating an index on a field in a table creates another data structure which holds the field value, and pointer to the record it relates to. This index structure is then sorted, allowing Binary Searches to be performed on it.